# OpenSSH in Windows PE 10

Tags: ssh, services, openssh, windows-services, winpe

I'm using WinPE10 (10586), that I've built using ADK10. I was going to install SSH Server in it. I've found only one suitable: OpenSSH.
But discovered, that I need sc.exe to use this server. I tried two versions: from Win7 (7601) and Win10 (1607). Both of them showed nothing and returned code 1639.
Where can I find correct version for WinPE? Is it even possible to deploy any SSH server in WinPE?